# BigQueryOperator doesn't do autodetect

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, airflow, google-cloud-composer

`BigQueryOperator` doesn't do autodetect.
Column name becomes `string_field_*`.

When I run it on the Bigquery console it works, but when I try to run it in Cloud Composer it doesn't work.

```py
load_events = gcs_to_bq.GoogleCloudStorageToBigQueryOperator(
        task_id='load_events',
        bucket='*****',
        write_disposition='WRITE_TRUNCATE',
        source_objects=['****.csv'],
        destination_project_dataset_table='****.****',
        source_format='CSV',
        autodetect=True
)
```

please tell me what to do?

Comment: Look at https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/schema-detect#csv_header which will explain the behavior. Sadly it seems to be by design.

Comment: thank you very much.This issue has been resolved.